# SQL Join with Value Missing in One Column

Tags: mysql, sql-server, join

I'm trying to create a SQL query that uses one table to count the number of blade servers our company has in each chassis and groups those, while joining it with chassis information from another table.

However, one of the chassis has no blades in it, so the name does not appear in the blade inventory table. Using an INNER JOIN creates a table that doesn't contain that blade in any capacity. A LEFT JOIN achieves the same effect, but a RIGHT JOIN gives me an extra row with a null value for the chassis name.

I'm guessing this is because the non-existence of that blade name in the first table is being given precedence over the second, but not sure how to correct that. My query, as of now, looks like this:

```
SELECT e.EnclosureName, e.PDUName, q.Blades, r.Serial#
  FROM bladeinventory.table e JOIN
(
    SELECT EnclosureName,COUNT(*) Blades 
      FROM bladeinventory.table
      GROUP BY EnclosureName
) q ON e.EnclosureName = q.EnclosureName
LEFT JOIN chassisinventory.table r
ON e.EnclosureName = r.EnclosureName
GROUP BY e.EnclosureName, e.PDUName, q.Blades, r.Serial#
```

Is it possible to edit this in such a way that the name of the chassis with 0 blades is actually generated by the query?

Comment: So, SQL Server or MySQL?

Comment: And once you've answered that one, and if you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Comment: Like Strawberry mentioned: please create a sqlfiddle ( http://www.sqlfiddle.com )

Comment: Sorry, this is SQL server. I will try to create a SQLfiddle ASAP, just juggling multiple problems at the moment. Thanks for your time, guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just pull the name from the `chassisinventory` table.  I'll use `coalesce()`, just in case you switch the order of the `join`s (again):

```
SELECT COALESCE(r.EncloseName, e.EnclosureName) as EnclosureName, e.PDUName, q.Blades, r.Serial#
FROM bladeinventory.table e JOIN
     (SELECT EnclosureName,COUNT(*) Blades 
      FROM bladeinventory.table
      GROUP BY EnclosureName
     ) q
     ON e.EnclosureName = q.EnclosureName LEFT JOIN
     chassisinventory.table r
     ON e.EnclosureName = r.EnclosureName
GROUP BY COALESCE(r.EncloseName, e.EnclosureName), e.PDUName, q.Blades, r.Serial#;
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this code presented the original problem in mine. The chassis with no blades in it is not present in the table. Thank you for your response, though!

Comment: @Justin . . . Just change the `left join` to a `right join` or put the table as first in a series of `left joins`.

Comment: Argh, of course! I was trying this and the other answer at the same time, and that came closer off the bat, so I was working there without switching the join. Still working to memorize how all of these Join types work together. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

You can also use below code where case is being used which is much simpler and effective

```
SELECT e.EnclosureName, r.PDUName, 
case when q.Blades IS NULL then 0 
else q.Blades end Blades, 
e.Serial#
FROM chassisinventory.table e
LEFT OUTER JOIN bladeinventory.table r on e.EnclosureName = r.EnclosureName
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT EnclosureName,COUNT(*) Blades 
  FROM bladeinventory.table
  GROUP BY EnclosureName
) q on e.EnclosureName = q.EnclosureName
```

Comment: This comes very close in that it does incorporate the missing chassis, however there's something off with how its grouping things and each chassis is repeated for as many blades as are in them. I'm working from this code to try and create the desired result. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Justin Can you give me an Idea how the o/p should look like? i.e. Whether ever Encloser name from chassis will be present in blade or not?